Boundary properties of the convex envelope
Let
$\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, bounded and strictly convex, i.e. for all
$x, y \in \overline{\Omega}$
and
$\lambda \in (0, 1)$
we have that
$$ 
\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y \in \Omega.
$$
Furhermore, let
$g \colon \partial \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
be continuous and define
$$
G(x) :=
\sup\{
    h(x) \mid 
    h \colon \overline{\Omega} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} 
    \text{ is convex and } 
    h|_{\partial \Omega} \leq g 
\}
$$
for all $x \in \overline{\Omega}$.
I want to show that $G$ is continuous and satisfies $G|_{\partial \Omega} = g$.
I know that $G$ is convex and therefore (locally Lipschitz) continuous on $\Omega$. Hence I must fix an arbitrary point $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$ and show that $G$ is continuous at $x_0$ and satisfies $G(x_0) = g(x_0)$. How can do this?
I have some ideas of my own here. I may be able to show that $G$ is lower semicontinuous at $x_0$ and that $G(x_0) = g(x_0)$. To do so I want to show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an affine map $P \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
g(x_0) - \varepsilon < P(x_0) < g(x_0)
\quad \text{and} \quad
P|_{\partial\Omega} < g.
$$
In general I'm thinking that perhaps the supporting hyperplane theorem might become neccecary in order to construct such an affine map $Q$. If additional smoothness assumption are imposed upon $\partial \Omega$ then perhaps a more straightforward argument will suffice.
Even if the above works, I must still prove that $G$ is upper semicontinuous at $x_0$. At the moment I have no idea how to do this. I will accept ideas that require $\partial \Omega$ to be smooth in some sense, but I prefer the more general case. Any help is appreciated.

Just a few ideas: Take $P(x) = g(x)-\varepsilon - K \langle x-x_0, \nu \rangle$ for a large $K$ and an inner normal $\nu$ (the existence of which requires some smoothness on $\partial \Omega$). Close to $x_0$ this function is below $g$ and further away from $x_0$ we have $\langle x-x_0, \nu\rangle \ge \eta>0$ for some $\eta>0$ by strict convexity of $\Omega$. Since $g$ is bounded we can choose $K$ large enough such that $P \le g$ on the whole boundary $\partial \Omega$.
For continuity mirroring the construction could work: $\tilde P(x) = g(x) + \varepsilon + K \langle x-x_0, \nu \rangle$.

Can you expand on your continuity argument? How does the plane $\tilde{P}$ help me?

My idea was, that near the boundary you can squeeze $g$ between $P$ and $\overline P$, which in the limit would imply $g(x_0)- \varepsilon \le \lim_{n \to \infty} g(x_n) \le g(x_0)+\varepsilon$ for a sequence $(x_n)_n \subset \Omega$ which converges to $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$. This would show $\lim g(x_n)= g(\lim x_n) = g(x_0)$ by letting $\varepsilon \to 0$.

But $\tilde{P}$ is not among the convex functions considered in the supremum by which the convex envelope is defined, so I don't see how it can be used to infer an upper bound. Anyway, I was able to prove the result myself. I'll update my post whenever I have the time.
